# Distribution equivalence of $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ (i.e. standard normal) random variables.

My book says that

> the [random variables] $\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\frac{X}{|Y|}$ are identically distributed by symmetry of the standard Normal distribution.

I don't see it.  After all, the numerators are identical (hence, trivially identically distributed), but the denominators ($Y$ and $|Y|$) are *not* identically distributed ($Y$'s support is the real line, while $|Y|$'s support is only the non-negative closed ray of the real line.)

I can prove this equivalence using a *very messy* argument based on the Law of Total Probability, but I'd really like to understand the symmetry argument.  I'm looking for a more spelled out version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
P\left(\frac{X}{Y}\leq z\right) & = & P\left(Y>0\wedge X\leq zY\right) & + & P\left(Y<0\wedge X\geq zY\right)\\
 & = & P\left(Y>0\wedge X\leq zY\right) & + & P\left(Y<0\wedge-X\geq zY\right)\\
 & = & P\left(Y>0\wedge X\leq zY\right) & + & P\left(Y<0\wedge X\leq-zY\right)\\
 & = & P\left(Y>0\wedge X\leq z|Y|\right) & + & P\left(Y<0\wedge X\leq z|Y|\right)\\
 & = & P\left(\frac{X}{|Y|}\leq z\right)
\end{array}$$

Note that only the symmetry of $X$ and $P(Y=0)=0$ are used.

---

**edit** (inspired by comment of @Did):

Crucial is of course the equality $P\left(Y<0\wedge X\geq zY\right)=P\left(Y<0\wedge-X\geq zY\right)$ which is actually true because $\langle X,Y\rangle$ and $\langle -X,Y\rangle$ have equal probabilities.

This follows from:$$P(X\leq x\wedge Y\leq y)=P(X\leq x)P(Y\leq y)=P(-X\leq x)P(Y\leq y)=P(-X\leq x\wedge Y\leq y)$$

Here it is used that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $X$ and $-X$ have equal distribution.

Comment: One can note that, in addition to the symmetry of $Y$, **the independence of $(X,Y)$ is required** for the crucial step $$P\left(Y<0\wedge X\geq zY\right)= P\left(Y<0\wedge-X\geq zY\right)$$ to ensure that $(X,Y)$ and $(-X,Y)$ are identically distributed.

Comment: @Did "in addition to the symmetry of $Y$" Is that used somewhere then?

Comment: Right, "in addition to the symmetry of $X$", not of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$X=-X$ in distribution (i.e. $X$ is symmetric about $0$.)

Now consider $Z=\dfrac{X}{Y}$, if $Y> 0$, and $\dfrac{X}{-Y}$ if $Y< 0$.

Then $P(Z\leq z)=P\Big(\dfrac{X}{Y}\leq z, Y>0\Big)+P\Big(\dfrac{X}{-Y}\leq z, Y<0\Big)\\=P(X\leq zY, Y>0)+P(X\leq -zY, Y<0)(*)\\=P(X\leq zY, Y>0)+P(-X\geq zY, Y<0)\\=P(X\leq zY, Y>0)+P(X\geq zY, Y<0)\space\space\text{(since symmetry of $X$ about $0$)}\\=P(\dfrac{X}{Y}\leq z, Y>0)+P(\dfrac{X}{Y}\leq z, Y<0)\\=P(\dfrac{X}{Y}\leq z)$

Note that $Z=\dfrac{X}{\mid Y\mid}$

Hence $\dfrac{X}{\mid Y\mid}=\dfrac{X}{Y}$ in distribution.

Added:

$(*)$Note $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$, then $$P(X\leq -zY,Y<0)=\int_{y<0}P(X\leq -zy\mid Y=y)\phi(y)dy\\=\int_{y<0}P(X\leq -zy)\phi(y)dy\space\text{($X$ and $Y$ independent)}\\=\int_{y<0}\Phi(-zy) \phi(y)dy=\int_{y<0}[1-\Phi(zy)] \phi(y)dy\\=\int_{y<0}[P(X> zy)] \phi(y)dy=P(X\geq zY, Y<0)$$

Comment: The symmetry of $X$ and $Y$ about $0$ are both important here, not just $Y$, and should be stated explicitly in deriving (1)

Comment: I would have said that $\frac{X}{Y},\frac{-X}{Y},\frac{X}{-Y},\frac{-X}{-Y}$ all have identical distributions due to symmetry about $0$ and so (1) is true. Thinking about it more, given independence of $X$ and $Y$, you may only need one of them to be symmetric about $0$

Comment: Thanks @Henry I did not know that was needed here, anyway, thanks.

Comment: Sorry but why is the (true) fact that the distributions of $X/Y$ and $-X/Y$ coincide, supposed to imply that the distributions of $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$ coincide?

Comment: Yes you already said that this implication is direct and I asked you why. Repeating that it is direct does not help a iota. If it is indeed direct, please provide the argument. (The link in your answer seems quite unrelated.)

Comment: You added the step that $$P\left(X/(-Y)\leq z\mid Y<0\right)=P\left(X/Y\leq z\mid Y<0\right)$$ That is, $$P\left(X\leq -zY, Y<0\right)=P\left(X\geq zY, Y<0\right)$$ At least some further explanation why this holds seems mandatory, no? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the fact that $X/Y$ and $-X/Y$ coincide in distribution (that is, your (1), if I am not mistaken) does **not** imply the desired identity.

Comment: @Did it's like I should call you and ask you why(not possible though).... anyway $X=_d Y$, then $P(X\leq z)=P(Y\leq z)$, then $P(X\leq z, A)=P(Y\leq z, A)\Rightarrow P(X\leq z\mid A)=P(Y\leq z\mid A)$.... is this derivation wrong???

Comment: That depends very much on $A$. Unless $A$ is independent of $(X,Y)$, there is no reason this should hold.

Comment: You are repeating the same mistake as before when stating: $$P(-X\geq zY, Y<0)=P(X\geq zY, Y<0)\space\space\text{(since symmetry of $X$ about $0$)}$$ The symmetry of $X$ certainly does not suffice for this to hold.

Comment: @Did is this calculation right: $$P(X\leq -zY,Y<0)=\int_{y<0}P(X\leq -zy)\phi(y)dy\\=\int_{y<0}\Phi(-zy) \phi(y)dy=\int_{y<0}[1-\Phi(zy)] \phi(y)dy\\=\int_{y<0}[P(X> zy)] \phi(y)dy=P(X\geq zY, Y<0)$$

Comment: @Did if it is right it follows from $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$, which hold if $X$ is symmetric about $0$.

Comment: The key step lies in the first = sign and in the last = sign of your previous to last comment. Can you justify these? Once you will have given the proper argument, I invite you to rewrite all your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Did if $X,Y$ are independent then $$P(X\leq zY)=\int_{y}P(X\leq zy\mid Y=y)dF_Y(y)=\int_{y}P(X\leq zy)dF_Y(y)$$ Is this fit for the argument you are telling?

Comment: Yup. Well done.

Comment: ?? Should you? Of course you should! What have I been telling you for almost uncountably many comments, one wonders...